# How send a object or array from html page into the POST method, using Thymeleaf with spring

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have a html page with next code:

```
<div class="w3-container w3-light-grey">
    <div class="w3-container w3-grey">

    <form th:action="@{'/wordprocess/' + ${descriptionId}}" method="post">
        <table class="w3-table-all w3-card-4">
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
               <th>Word</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tr th:each="wd : ${wordslist}">
                <td th:text="${wd.getId()}">Jill</td>
                <td th:text="${wd.getWord()}">Jill</td>
                <td th:if="${wd.getType() == 0}" th:text="word">Jill</td>
                <td th:if="${wd.getType() == 1}" th:text="skill">Jill</td>
                <td>
                    <p>
                        <input class="w3-check" type="checkbox" name="type" th:value="${wd.getType()}">
                        <label>Skill</label>
                   </p>
                </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    <input class="w3-button w3-black" type="submit" value="Save"/>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

in \p\ block i use checkbox for initialization types of object. Field 'type' can get a two integer values: 0 or 1.

I want to be able to specify the values of this type in the checkbox (1 - checked, 0 - unchecked) and get this array in the POST method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/wordprocess/{descriptionId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String save(
        @PathVariable long descriptionId,
        @RequestParam(value = "type", required = false) int[] type
){
    System.out.println(descriptionId);
    System.out.println(type[0]);
    return "index";
}
```

But in save() method I have a null value in 'type' variable.

How can I correctly send a set of checkbox values in POST method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First rule, with checkboxes/radio buttons, you don't get the unchecked items returned to the server, just the checked ones.  If you add an HttpServletRequest request to the argument list of your save() method (it will be auto-populated by Spring), you should be able to call `request.getParameterValues("type")` for the value attributes of all the checkboxes with a name of "type".  You'll want to update the value attributes of all those checkboxes to wd.getId() instead of wd.getType() so you'll have the ID's of the checked items.

Finally, to specify an initial checked/unchecked state, use `th:checked="${wd.getType()}"` instead of th:value for that (the latter of which will need to hold the id's as mentioned above.)

Comment: What type returns the request.getParameter...? And how to tie up ID's and checked items?

Comment: String[] s = request.getParameterValues("type") - anyway returns null

Comment: @Valeriy if you set the value of each checkbox to each item's ID, every ID you get will be of a checked item.  If its not checked, the information is not sent back to you.  If .getParameterValues("type") is returning null, I'd check the rendered HTML source in the browser to ensure both the name is being set to "type" for each checkbox and the value for each checkbox is set to the ID of the particular item in the loop.

Comment: thanks, thanks, thanks! Now I did all understand, all worked!